# Unable to Bookmark any finding

Tags: selenium

I have a scenario:

I need to hover on the finding and once hovered,the bookmark symbol is visible ,only then i can bookmark on the bookmark flag

```
    Wait Until Page Contains Element xpath=.//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]
    Mouse Over xpath=.//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]
    Wait Until Page Contains Element xpath=(.//div[@class='bookmarkPanel'])[1]
    Click Element xpath=(.//div[@class='bookmarkPanel'])[1]
```

Error: The element is not visible

Comment: So what exactly does this question have to do with PyCharm?

Comment: I am using pycharm IDE

Comment: So what? PyCharm does not affect the behavior of your Selenium tests in any way.